# Project Server 2013 Queue Issue

Tags: ms-project-server-2013

I have a code to assign users to task based on their role in the Project Server Resource Center.
The custom fields which are used are a Task Level "Task_Role" Field and Resource Level "Res_Role" 
Field. I am comparing the values in the both fields and assigning it to task.

When I try to iterate over tasks and make an assignment, I have to write the following: -

```
 QueueJob qJobtoUpdate = dp.Update();
 JobState jobState = projContext.WaitForQueue(qJobtoUpdate, timeoutSeconds);
```

This is done for every task in the project by running a loop, and then after the loop, I checkIn the project.

On analysing, I found that for every single task, the above line takes around 5-8 seconds, and hence makes this process slower.

Is there a solution for the above scenario. Kindly provide some pointers.

Thanks & regards,
Divyang Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

Just update the project once instead of each time you create a new assignment